# Onclick event fails but shows a syntax error

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function that is supposed to generate a `<div>` dynamically and populate the div using `<li></li>`. There is an `onclick` event on the `<li></li>` tags that calls a function but when clicked, the function does not show. Please help me. The console on my browser shows the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }.

A sample of my code is below:

```
function showItem(categoryName) {
    cleanDiv();
    var alphabet = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z";
    var alphabetArray = [];
    alphabetArray = alphabet.split(",");
    var stringData = '<div id="alphabet-menu"><h1>' + categoryName + '</h1><ul>';
    var letter;
    for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        letter = alphabetArray[i];
        stringData = stringData + '<li onclick="getData("' + categoryName + '","' + letter + '");">' + letter + '</li>';

    }
    stringData = stringData + '</ul></div><div id="list-menu"><input type="button" onclick="animateRight();"  value="Back"></input>' + '<div id="home-button" onclick="animateRight();"><img src="img/home.png"></div></div>';
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '' + stringData + '';
}

function getData(category, letter) {
    alert(category + letter);
}
```

Comment: *There is an onlick event ...* Delicious...

Comment: you should probably format your code properly and add some semicolons before worrying about syntax errors.

Comment: Surprisingly, your code seems to have all its curly braces matched. This probably means that your issue is somewhere else in your script. Also, I [cleaned and linted your code](http://pastebin.com/0XPncSEA) for you.

Comment: @jbabey Where? I think I've already done that.

Comment: @arxanas I only have those two functions in my script.

Comment: `'<li onclick="getData("'` is the issue - you need to escape your double quotes or they end the inline script call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code as below

```
letter = alphabetArray[i];
stringData = stringData+'<li onclick="getData(\''+categoryName+'\',\''+letter+'\');">'+letter+'</li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in `getData` declaration. Here's a working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/CfRBc/